# Is there any way to avoid three nested loops in this code?

Tags: javascript, performance, loops

I know this is question probably does not belong here, but if anyone is up for it, I could use some advice.

I'm wondering if there is any way to write the following code in a more efficient and effective way.

The general concept:

1. Go through a list of up to 6 neighbor measurement lists
2. Check if the list contains any illegal combinations (the combination of `arfcn` and `bsic`)
3. If illegal, add to an alarm list, if it does not already exist in this list.

Here is the code:

```
var bcch_sacch = [70, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
var combo = [[70, 30], [0, 0]]
var alarm;
var ncellcount = message.data.reports.numberofneighbors;

//Loop through neighbors measurements (up to 6)
for(var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {

    //If j is less than the amount of neighbors in the list (0-6)
    if(j < ncellcount) {

        //Combo: allowed combinations
        for(var i = 0; i < combo.length; i++) {

            //If allowed
            if(combo[i][0] == bcch_sacch[j] &&
               combo[i][1] == message.data.reports.neighboringCells[j].BSIC) {
            }
            else {
                for(var d = 0; d < alarm.length; d++) {

                    //If the current arfcn(j) and bsic(j) is in the alarms list
                    if(alarm[d][0] == bcch_sacch[j] &&
                       alarm[d][1] == message.data.reports.neighboringCells[j].BSIC) {

                    }
                    else {
                        //Add the combo in the alarm list
                        alarm[alarm.length][0] =  bcch_sacch[j];
                        alarm[alarm.length][1] = message.data.reports.neighboringCells[j].BSIC;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//Print out the alarms list in a table
for(var s = 0; s < alarm.length; s++) {
    $('#alarms tr:last').after('<tr><td>'+alarm[s][0]+'</td><td>'+alarm[s][1]+'</td></tr>');
}
```

Comment: To begin with, using Array.filter (for finding illegal combinaisons) and Array.some (for finding existing alarm) would probably make the code more readable.